# 6216m2 motor found... what to do?

Tags: motor

I recently found [a 6216m2 motor](http://rebrickable.com/parts/6216m2/electric-motor-4.5v-type-2-for-2-prong-connectors-with-middle-pin) in a jumble of old bricks and such - but 
no connection wires.

- Firstly, how does this motor compare against all others? As it is a 4.5V motor, it is not listed in [philo's list of motor comparisions](http://www.philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm), but I'd still be interested to know how it compares.
- Secondly, would there be much use for it, all comparisions made?
- Thirdly, I presume it should be simple enough to get replacement cables and such?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the 4.5V motors have higher torque than the higher voltage variants, but run at a much lower RPM.  I have never personally tested this particular motor so I can't say specifically.

Utility is in the eyes of the beholder.  For some people, this would be the exact motor they need.  For some, it would be useless.  It's hard to say if it would be useful/less without a specific application.

You can always order the LEGO branded cable/connectors from Bricklink or similar sites.  However, it's quite easy to make your own cabling for the 4.5V motors if you are so inclined.